# Black boxes everywhere on Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, 20.04, kde, visual-artifacts

I have recently installed Kubuntu desktop environment, but after installation it has the setting like older and it's showing black boxes everywhere.

[image]

Comment: I tried nothing happened sir.

Comment: It's not fuzzy graphics either, just black squares, so it must be something else idk.

Comment: Did you change a theme setting? This is a weird one. Those mostly look to be where icons would be.

Comment: this is not just about theme. I have these kind of boxes even on login screen. so i download xubuntu-desktop and it is working fine now.

Comment: @ViruTyagi Can you post an answer describing how you solved the problem? I think you're saying you solved it by installing the `xubuntu-desktop` metapackage. But I am not totally sure.

Comment: It is not solved. just I installed another DE and working on that.